# I am trying to write a trigger that transfers accounts records owned by a particular user when that user is deactivated

Tags: apex, trigger

The records need to be transferred to another certain type of user (The Mule Sync user). I am new to software development and this is my first trigger, so any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code so far.

I do not get any errors, but I am noticing that the accountRecords and deactivatedUsersIds lists are not populating. The problem is that the If-statement in the trigger is not being entered, but I am not sure why.

```
trigger trg_transferDeactivatedUserRecords on User (before update, after update) {
for (User u : Trigger.new) {
    List<Id> deactivatedUsersIds = new List<Id>();
    if (u.isActive == false && u.Profile.Name == 'Consumer Sales Community') {
        deactivatedUsersIds.add(u.Id);
        System.debug(':::deactivatedUsersIds:::'+deactivatedUsersIds);
    }
    System.debug(':::deactivatedUsersIds:::'+deactivatedUsersIds);
    TH_transferDeactivatedUserRecords.transferDeactivatedUserRecords(deactivatedUsersIds);
}
```

}

And below is the trigger handler

```
public class TH_transferDeactivatedUserRecords {
@future
public static void transferDeactivatedUserRecords(List<Id> deactivatedUsersIds) {
    List<Account> accountRecords = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = :deactivatedUsersIds LIMIT 1]; //REMOVE LIMIT AFTER TESTING
    System.debug(':::accountRecords:::'+accountRecords);
    List<User> newOwner = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'Mule Sync' AND Profile.Name = 'Africa Deploy and Integration Users' LIMIT 1];
    System.debug(':::newOwner:::'+newOwner);
    for (Account a : accountRecords) {
        a.OwnerId = newOwner[0].Id;
    }
    update accountRecords;
    System.debug(':::accountRecords-Updated:::'+accountRecords);
    
}
```

Comment: Do you have two triggers on the User object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `2nd Step`, where you are trying to get accounts owned by deactivated user, but instead retrieving accounts owned by the user who is deactivating (`UsefInfo.getUserId()`). Also you are retrieveing only one account for such user, you should remove `LIMIT 1` from SOQL. And finally, you are trying to retrieve accounts with `Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()` when you need to query it by `OwnerId = :u.Id` instead.

`2nd Step` should look like this:

```
List<Account> accountRecords = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = :u.Id];
```

Apart from the actual logical error, I also suggest you to read about bulkifying triggers, so that you won't have SOQL queries inside the loop. (Here is a useful [Trailhead Unit](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk)).

UPDATE FOR **MIXED_DML_OPERATION**:

```
DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa)
```

It means exactly what it tells, you cannot update User (setup object) and Account (non-setup object) in one transaction. Move accounts update to asynchronous Apex.

In the end you will have something like this (already bulkified):

**Apex Trigger**:

```
trigger trg_transferDeactivatedUserRecords on User (before update) {
    for (User u : Trigger.new) {
        List<Id> deactivatedUsersIds = new List<Id>();
        if (u.isActive == false && u.Name == 'Partner - Technician') {
            deactivatedUsersIds.add(u.Id);
        }
    }
    UserTriggerHandler.transferDeactivatedUserRecords(deactivatedUsersIds);
}
```

**Apex Class**:

```
public class UserTriggerHandler {
    @future
    public static void transferDeactivatedUserRecords(List<Id> deactivatedUsersIds) {
        List<Account> accountRecords = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE OwnerId IN :deactivatedUsersIds];
        List<User> newOwner = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'userName' AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' LIMIT 1];
        for (Account a : accountRecords) {
            a.OwnerId = newOwner[0].Id;
        }
        update accountRecords;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your reply. I have made the changes you recommended, but I am still getting the error in my edited post. Do you know how I can go about resolving this?

Comment: @Tristan Have updated my answer, please, take a look.

Comment: I am still getting a Mix DML error, however, it is telling me that it is still on line 34 , which I do not have in either the trigger or handler that you provided. I am not sure if this might be some sort of glitch from a previous test run?

Comment: Do you possibly have another trigger on user object? What class it says has error on line 34? If your class now doesn;t have this line, make sure you have saved the changes and rerun the tests.

Comment: Yes, you are correct!! I did have another very similar named trigger from a past attempt that I forgot about. I deleted it and it ran with no errors! I will still need to go through a more thorough testing process with a senior dev on my team on Monday, but for now, no errors. Thank you for all your help Mariia :)!!!

Comment: You are welcome)

Comment: Hi again Mariia, I have updated the post. Do you perhaps know why the If-statement in the trigger is not being entered?